# IIS 10.0 SSI error: #EXEC calls have been disabled for this virtual path

Tags: iis, windows-10, ssi, server-side-includes

My IIS skills leave a lot to be desired but I've been asked to enable the SSI #exec directive for someone and I'm running into a problem:  I can get SSI #echo to work, and I have this in both the `applicationHost.config` and the `web.config` in the web root:

```xml
<serverSideInclude ssiExecDisabled="false" />
```

But with this in my `index.shtml` file:

```html
<!--#echo var="LOCAL_ADDR"--><br>
<!--#exec cmd="echo hello">-->
```

I get the output:

```
127.0.0.1
#EXEC calls have been disabled for this virtual path
```

I haven't explicitly set up any virtual paths and my `index.shtml` file is in the web root. I've searched using four search engines for that error message and can't find it mentioned anywhere.

If anyone can tell me how to get the #exec command to work, I'll really appreciate it!

The server is Microsoft-IIS/10.0 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Thank you kindly,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

try to set add the DWORD registry value SSIEnableCmdDirective to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters key, and set it to 1.

assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the cmd.exe file. or run the app pool under the custom user account which has full access permission to the access cmd.exe file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525620(v%3Dvs.90)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  I added the registry value and it didn't work. I tried to change the permissions on the cmd.exe file, but after clicking the Edit button in the cmd.exe Properties dialog, all of the options are grayed out.  So I created a new AppPool with the identity of a user in the Users group (which has Read&Exec and Read access) but that didn't work either. I tried changing .NET to "No Managed Code" but still no luck. I'll appreciate any other suggestions you or anyone else can offer!